# How should I return this remote JSON data from my Node.js module?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am learning Node.js and I have searched all over the place to understand how to handle this bit of code. I am writing a module that communicates with an open API. It basically requests for a JSON and returns it to the caller that `require`s this moule.

This is inside a `module.exports` function:

```
// prep URL

var request = require('request');
request({
    url: requestURL,
    json: true
}, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);     // need to return this data 
    }
});
```

Instead of `console.log(body)`, I want to return the body back from this function. But because the callback function is asynchronous, it does not work.

I can make a callback function, but I want to return the data from this `module.exports` function, so that would be weird. I could put this `request` code in a helper function instead of the `module.exports` function, but I cannot figure out how to return the data back anyway.

Should I organize my code in some other way?

Comment: that's not the full, minimal code (i.e., enough code to cover all the variables and dependencies you're showing). What's your module's actual code?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans My snippet is from a module.exports function. Before this snippet, I have just prepped the requestURL. The only thing left is to return the data.

Comment: cool. show that in your post please =)

Comment: Reorganize your code. Pass a callback to your `module.exports` function and call it in the handler of `request`. Generally you can't force asynchronous functions to be synchronous.

Comment: Return a promise for the data as `exports`.

Comment: Maybe you can return an EventEmitter then the module listeners will attach to its 'done'. Still async, but at least the module is sync and three is no callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding a callback function to my API. This way, the parent module can choose what to do with the retrieved JSON data.